# Oracle Fusion Middleware Installation Unexpected Error Nullpointer Exception

Tags: java, weblogic12c

While installing OFM 12.2.1 on a Windows machine, I am getting a NullPointerException at Installation Location Window.

In logs :

> Unable to locate type distribution in namespace http://xmlns.oracle.com/cie/gdr/dbd

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error is because I have a blank space in my username in Windows, and the path of temporal files is "C:\sdfdf\gdfg gxsfd\", I replace the temp variable for "C:\temp".

This is the solution.